# TortoiseSVN can't connect to repository due to timeout

Tags: svn, connection, tortoisesvn

I want to checkout source code from the repository. I have a link via https protocol. I can open this link in web browser and I can see all files and their content. However, the latest version of TortoiseSVN can't connect to the repository and the standard error appears: "Unable to connect to a repository at URL: https://... Connection timed out".

Could you please advice me how can resolve this issue?

Comment: Ask your Network Admin or here on SF|SU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy or firewall in front of Apache, which allow plain-HTTP, but disallow WebDAV (which is spoken by any SVN-client)